# What does the `model.parameters()` include?

Tags: python, parameters, deep-learning, pytorch

In Pytorch,

What will be registered into the `model.parameters()`.

As far as now, what I know are as belows:

```
1.  Conv layer: weight  bias
2.  BN layers: weight(gamma)  bias(beta)
3.  nn.Parameter() 
    such as:   self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(10))  defined in the model.
```

My **question** is:
And are there some parameters else that are registered in the `model.parameters()` ?

**PS**. The most common case for the `model.parameters()` is in the optimizer,
e.g.  [pytorch resnet example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L171-L173)

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), args.lr,
                                momentum=args.momentum,
                                weight_decay=args.weight_decay)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Like you wrote there, `model.parameters()` stores the weight and bias (if set to true) values of the model.
It is given as an argument to an optimizer to update the weight and bias values of the model with one line of code `optimizer.step()`, which you then use when next you go over your dataset.